# Use Arial in Overleaf

Tags: xetex, overleaf, arial

I'm writting my final degree project in **Overleaf**, using **XeLaTeX**.

One of the main requierements is to use **Arial font** in the entire document.

And here is where the problem begins... I've tried many many different ways to make it work (import my own ttf's, using fontspect, but nothing seems to work).

Right now in the preamble I'm using:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

But, if I go to any section, lets say **Introduction**, the font is still the same... I also have (in a different *.tex* file) a 'page' acting as a cover page (which I reference in the first page), and still, the text is the same, when I use fontspec and when I don't.

Any help is appreciated, merry christmas y'all.

Comment: Arial is a propertiary font and not part of a normal tex system. If you have it you can to upload it (but check if your license allows it).

Comment: One of your other packages must be changing the font. Could you please post a Minimal Working Example so we can see what packages you are loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use:

```
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

at the beginning of my document:

```
\begin{document}
    ...
    \setmainfont{Arial}
    ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: That should not be necessary. What other packages are you loading?

Comment: `\setmainfont{Arial}` under the document is not really necessary and makes any big difference. You technically need to use a different compiler, either `lualatex` or `xelatex` in overleaf.